# Some strange behavior inserting an Element in python 3.7 ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm getting an error in some code, that used to work in python 2.7.  I'm in the debugger, right before some code is inserting an Element

```
(Pdb) ET.Element
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
(Pdb) xxx = ET.Element(component.PROPERTY,name=CODE_LANGUAGE_PPTY,value=codeLanguage)
(Pdb) xxx
<Element 'property' at 0x102d00c10>
(Pdb) type(xxx)
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
(Pdb) cmpxml
<Element 'component' at 0x102cfd6b0>
(Pdb) type(cmpxml)            
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
(Pdb) cmpxml.insert(0, xxx)
*** TypeError: insert() argument 2 must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not Element
(Pdb) type(xxx)
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>

(Pdb) print(sys.version)
3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:27:02) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
```

`xxx` is clearly a `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`.  Can anyone explain why this is failing?  I read some stuff saying that the type checks in ElementTree were added at Python 3.4, but I don't understand why it thinks `xxx` is an `Element` (whatever that is) when `type(xxx)` says it IS a `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`.

My import look like (pretty ordinary):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions..

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the `cmpxml` node? I'm not able to reproduce the problem just making my own random nodes so far.

Comment: In regards to the "type checks" - Python 3.4 added type _annotations_, or _type hints_. There's no hard type checking done by the interpreter itself. Arbitrary code can do the `if isinstance()` check, but that's been around for longer than Python 3.4 has.

Comment: `type(cmpxml) is type(xxx)` might be interesting to try.  One possible explanation for problems like this is that you've somehow managed to import the same module twice - for example, with two different capitalizations on a case-insensitive filesystem.  This leads to having two sets of classes that describe themselves identically, but neither is compatible with the other in any way.

Comment: Please provide code that we can copy, paste and run ([mcve]).

Comment: @b_c I read an issue, that suggested that ElementTree.add and .insert were going to ADD a type check (isinstance).  OK, I found it, https://bugs.python.org/issue13782 .

Comment: @jasonharper I think something like this must be the issue and it should be easy enough to to do a search.  I hadn't thought about the case sensitivity (I'm on macos, so its relevant) and hadn't realized this sort of issue (duplicate module loads) could occur in python.  It's annoyingly common in Java with use of multiple class loaders.

Comment: I stared and wandered around the code for a while, and couldn't figure out where the issue was occurring.  Creating a minimal reproducible example did not evidence the problem.  However, replacing the calls to  ```ET.Element(...)``` with ```cmpxml.makeelement()``` fixed the issue, presumably by not using the "imposter" xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.  Thanks for the help.